# Maximum call stack size exceeded error but only at certain div

Tags: jquery

I just wanted to make a small script where if i click a div, a button triggers. 
but if i use a certain div as selector value it shouts out the error is mentioned.

HTML

```
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;background:red;" id="test"></div>
    <div id="upload_wrapper">
        <span id="upload_text"><b>Datei auswählen</b> oder per Drag & Drop hinzufügen</span>
        <form action="upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="form_file_select"></label><br/>
            <span id="file_selected"></span>
            <input id="form_file_select" type="file" name="form_file_select"><br/>
            <button type="submit" id="form_file_submit" name="form_file_submit" style="visibility: hidden;">Hochladen</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#upload_wrapper").on("click", function(){
            $("#form_file_select").click();
        });
    });
```

if i use the test div or an other element inside the #upload_wrapper as the selector everything works finde. But if i use the #upload_wrapper it doesnt work. Any Idea why?

Comment: You're raising an event within the event handler which catches the event. It's an infinite loop. A much better idea is to get rid of the outer `div` and JS code and just use a `label` to expand the hit area for the `input`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the HTML code to be as follows:

```html
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;background:red;" id="test"></div>
    <div id="upload_wrapper">
        <span id="upload_text"><b>Datei auswählen</b> oder per Drag & Drop hinzufügen</span>
    </div>
    <form action="upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="form_file_select"></label><br/>
        <span id="file_selected"></span>
        <input id="form_file_select" type="file" name="form_file_select"><br/>
        <button type="submit" id="form_file_submit" name="form_file_submit" style="visibility: hidden;">Hochladen</button>
    </form>
```